# Godot: How would I get InputEventMouseMotion in the _process function?

Tags: input, game-engine, godot

I was working on a game in Godot and want to get this:

```
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        pass
```

in the _process function (without using _input or _unhandled_input or anything related or defining a new function)

Is there a way to do this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
Input.get_last_mouse_speed()
```

But this looks tricky to get right. From the official documentation:

> Returns the mouse speed for the last time the cursor was moved, and this until the next frame where the mouse moves. This means that even if the mouse is not moving, this function will still return the value of the last motion.

Using the _input function is a better solution. If you want to handle mouse movement in _process, you can use _input to store the movement in a variable, which is then read in _process.

Note that this is only a problem for the motion. You can easily get the state of the mouse buttons from Input (get_mouse_button_mask).

Comment: I tried this before, but I was unable to get it working while the mouse mode was set to captured.

Comment: With "this" you mean reading the mouse movement in _input? If that is the case I suggest you post a new question (with the code that doesn't work for you), since that is a different topic.

Comment: `event.relative` should be accessible even when using captured mouse mode. Other mouse properties aren't guaranteed to work when the mouse is captured as the mouse cursor will always be back to the center every frame (which is how captured mouse mode works).